# Polygonscan - Wrong token balance

Tags: transactions, etherscan

I'm trying to figure out why a transaction on polygonscan doesn't give me the correct value of my token balance.

If you step by step try to add and subtract the values, it will come out a different amount than what is listed at the top.

My trans address: 0x94b7151c0b11daf1a6809f0e56c190ec38fe12d4

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: What token are you asking about?

Comment: Oh sorry, I did not add link: https://polygonscan.com/token/0x64a795562b02830ea4e43992e761c96d208fc58d?a=0x94b7151c0b11daf1a6809f0e56c190ec38fe12d4

Comment: Sorry, I can't say anything definitive because the contract source isn't verified. There are tokens that charge fees on transfers, will rebalance the amounts or pay dividends, etc. There are also scam tokens that have a backdoor that allow the owner the remove liquidity.